# big foreach loop getting slower

Tags: c#

First, sorry for my English, it's not my main language. Second, I'll do my best trying to explain myself, but if something is unclear I can provide any details. I'm a bit unexperienced, let's start.

I have a big foreach loop, with 39k elements.

```
foreach (Busqueda.CodDesCIE elemResult in result.listaCodDesCIE)
            {
                timer.Restart();
                elemResultExterno = new getCodBusquedaResponse.ResultadoBusquedaResponse(elemResult.IdBuzon_Detalle, elemResult.Orden, elemResult.TipoAcierto, elemResult.ObjCIE10.Codigo, elemResult.ObjCIE10.Deslarga, elemResult.Cie10Adic1, elemResult.Cie10Adic2);
                listaResult.Add(elemResultExterno);
                param += " IdBuzon_Detalle:" + elemResultExterno.IdBuzonDetalle + " Orden:" + elemResultExterno.Orden + " TipoAcierto:" + elemResultExterno.TipoAcierto + " Codigo:" + elemResultExterno.Codigo + " Descripcion:" + elemResultExterno.Descripcion + " CodAdic1:" + elemResultExterno.CodAdic1 + " CodAdic2:" + elemResult.Cie10Adic2 + "\r\n";
                timer.Stop();
                Logger.Current.InfoLog("timerPartial: " + timer.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(), "itemNumber", orden.ToString());

                orden++;
            }
```

new getCodBusquedaResponse.ResultadoBusquedaResponse()

The problem is that each iteration, takes less than 0ms, for the first... 6k or more elements, but iteration time starts growing at that point, reaching up to 5ms in the final iterations. Ocasionally, I also see some peeks (dunno if you call it like that, "hight points") where an iteration might take 80ms, or 100ms.

I would like to know, why the time keeps growing, if it is normal, if it is easy to avoid...and some help / explanations on how I could optimize this code.

Log: Time is in ms

```
[INFO] - itemNumber.2() - timerPartial: 0
[INFO] - itemNumber.7666() - timerPartial: 0
[INFO] - itemNumber.7667() - timerPartial: 1
[INFO] - itemNumber.7725() - timerPartial: 81
[INFO] - itemNumber.23579() - timerPartial: 3
[INFO] - itemNumber.24356() - timerPartial: 101
[INFO] - itemNumber.28144() - timerPartial: 5
[INFO] - itemNumber.29201() - timerPartial: 6
[INFO] - itemNumber.33997() - timerPartial: 5
[INFO] - itemNumber.33998() - timerPartial: 6
[INFO] - itemNumber.38547() - timerPartial: 80
foreachLoop.() - timerTotal: 239389
```

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: `List<getCodBusquedaResponse.ResultadoBusquedaResponse> listaResult`

EDIT2: Many of you seem to point out the paramString. This code is not 100% mine so not sure if that is actually needed, will try with some of your suggestions or even commenting that line and give some feedback, thanks.

EDIT3: WOW. Commented the string line: foreachLoop.() - timerTotal: 20343

Didn't knew about this issue. For now, this will make it. For sure, will try CarbineCoder suggestion and Eiver also. If that also helps, then great, any time I can save will be welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should post your `getCodBusquedaResponse.ResultadoBusquedaResponse` code, as it seems the problem must be there

Comment: Because you're appending to an ever-growing string, the peaks most likely are the garbage collector kicking in, and what type is `listaResult`? Also, whichever `Timer` you're using most likely isn't precise enough to give accurate timing results. Anyway Stack Overflow is not "optimize my code", _you_ will need to identify the slow parts and ask specific questions on how to improve those.

Comment: What is `listaResult`?

Comment: There is no way for us to determine where your time gets lost, you need a profiling-tool such as DotTrace for this. This will help you identify performance-issues.

Comment: probably because `param` keeps getting re-created

Comment: you keep concatenating the string `param` - this is bad as strings are immutable, so a new string is created in memory and both values are held. If that loop is running 39k times, you could have 39k strings being stored in memory (depending on when the garbage collector runs). This could cause a performance issue.

Comment: The suggestion that this is due to collection pressure on the heap seem plausible but you should use good engineering practice. Get a memory profiler and find out *for sure* how much memory pressure you are producing, and whether that pressure on the "space" side accounts for your observations on the "time" side.

Comment: @EricLippert Why do that over just using a CPU profiler? You could just see how long each operation takes.

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis: Because if the performance charge is due to the garbage collector, there's not going to be a hot spot of code to tune; the problem will have to be dealt with by finding the hot spot of allocations and fixing that. If it turns out that memory usage is fine and GCs are not the cause of the problem, then you have falsified the hypothesis and can move on to the next hypothesis, and choose a tool to falsify or confirm it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One bad thing I noticed is you are appending `param` string variable. Which will create a lot of throw away objects within your loop. Instead use a string builder.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()
foreach (Busqueda.CodDesCIE elemResult in result.listaCodDesCIE)
{
   ..
    builder.Append(" IdBuzon_Detalle:").Append( elemResultExterno.IdBuzonDetalle);//etc.....
}
param = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Let's not throw random optimizations at a question like this. The OP should be perfectly able to identify this problem themselves, then find this exact suggestion as it's been suggested before a couple of thousands of times.

Comment: He will need to do more than introduce a `StringBuilder` to optimize this code...

Comment: Tried this: foreachLoop.() - timerTotal: 26532. Adds 6 seconds to the whole thing, acceptable. Anyway, gotta see if I really need that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: As others have suggested earlier, check for each method within the loop which is causing the issue. Mine is not the answer to your problem, its more of a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

CarbineCoder answer is one obvious optimization.

The other one being:

```
var listaResult= new List<getCodBusquedaResponse.ResultadoBusquedaResponse>(YOUR_EXPECTED_CAPACITY);
```

Try these.
If they do not work. Update your question so that it doesn't include methods, that are unknown to us.

Comment: Tried this after commenting the string. - timerTotal: 20328. Time is still the same, but thanks for the try anyway. This is already acceptable